# Visual Basic: File is said to be in the wrong folder

Tags: vb.net, file

Ok, here is my story:

I am building a fileviewer, and i am trying to delete the selected file in the listview.

when i try to delete it, it gave me an error saying the file wasnt found.  I looked at my desktop and the file was there.  here is the original code:

```
dim f as string = lv1.focuseditem.text
my.computer.filesystem.deletfile(f)
lv1.update()
```

this gave me that error.  My updated code is supposed to show me where the computer thinks my file is:

```
Dim file As String = lv1.FocusedItem.Text
Dim testFile As System.IO.FileInfo
testFile = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFileInfo(file)
Dim folderPath As String = testFile.DirectoryName
MsgBox(folderPath)
```

this shows a messagebox that shows the path of:

C:\Users\tgs266\Desktop\SIOS\SIOS\SIOS\obj\Debug\test.txt

but the real file location is:

C:\Users\tgs266\Desktop\test.txt

please help

Comment: when you load the file(s) into the listview, store the full filename as a subitem (if you dont add a column header it wont show).  then when you want to delete, use that subitem.  ALso, subitems can have names, so you can track what you are storing to make that easier.  "test" is a pretty bad name because you could have more than one in multiple locations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you getting the filenames for the `ListView`?  Is it just the filename and no path?

If, for example, `lv1.FocusedItem.Text` is "test.txt", and that is the value you use (without the path), by default the program will look in the directory it's executing in.  This is most likely why you're seeing `C:\Users\tgs266\Desktop\SIOS\SIOS\SIOS\obj\Debug\test.txt` as the location, instead of what you expected.

If all the files are on your desktop, you can use [Environment.GetFolderPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14tx8hby%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) in conjunction with the [Environment.SpecialFolder Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) to get the file, like this:

```
Dim file As String = lv1.FocusedItem.Text
Dim testFile As System.IO.FileInfo
testFile = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFileInfo(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + "\" + file)
Dim folderPath As String = testFile.DirectoryName 
MsgBox(folderPath)
```

However, if you're going to have files scattered throughout your system, you'd be better off storing the full path as @Plutonix indicates in his comment.

Comment: that really long path name actually looks like a VS project folder (`Obj\Debug`) and with generic names like that he could be chasing ghosts - there apparently ARE 2 'test' files on the system: one in debug @tgs266 gets back from fileinfo and another on the desktop

Comment: @Plutonix - I agree it looks like a VS project folder.  I would expect it to look in bin\debug actually, but I'm not as familiar with VB.NET as I am with C#, so there could be something VB special going on.  In any event, it's hard to give a more detailed answer without knowing more about what OP is putting in the ListView.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your code is looking in your applications path on the server while you want to look at the users desktop location.

Comment: You will need to navigate to the users directory... look at using Server Environment values.

Comment: my program doesnt have a server on it

Comment: No... Even though you have an exe on a workstation you will be able to use Environment values... in this context the Server is the machine that is running the application.

Comment: can you post me some source code or something because i am not following you

Comment: Look at http://windowsitpro.com/systems-management/what-environment-variables-are-available-windows

Comment: so i can use these in vb

Comment: these are not what i need